# CombineLatest causes multiple stream submissions

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to merge three streams that represent the initial state of the array, added elements and edited elements. Only add or edit emissions are expected to be performed at a time.
However, `combineLatest` fires two times which causes a new trip added to the array twice.

```
private initialTripsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Trip[]>([]);
  initialTrips$ = this.initialTripsSubject.asObservable();
  private newTripSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Trip>(null);
  addedTrip$ = this.newTripSubject.asObservable();
  private updatedTripSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Trip>(null);
  editedTrip$ = this.updatedTripSubject.asObservable();
  updatedTrips$ = combineLatest([
    this.initialTrips$,
    this.addedTrip$,
    this.editedTrip$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([existingTrips, newTrip, editedTrip]) => {
        if (editedTrip) {
          existingTrips.map(item => {
            if (editedTrip && item.id === editedTrip.id) {
              item.country = editedTrip.country;
              item.departureDate = editedTrip.departureDate;
              item.arrivalDate = editedTrip.arrivalDate;
              item.notes = editedTrip.notes;
            }
            return item;
          });
        }
        if (newTrip) {
          existingTrips.push(newTrip);
        }
        return existingTrips;
      }
    )
);
```

The event is emitted to addedTrip$ from this function

```
 addTrip(newTrip: Trip): void {
    this.newTripSubject.next(newTrip);
  }
```

In the template, the stream is used via `| async`

```
 <table *ngIf="(trips$ | async) as trips; else emptyTrips" class="table table-striped">
```

My assumption is when the `addedTrip$` is handled it changes the state of `initialTrips$` that causes the second fire of `combineLatest`.

Tried to split the merge of the streams into two parts: `merge(editedTips, addedTrip)`, and `combineLatest([initialTrips, resultOfMerge])`, but it didn't help.

How can I avoid double firing of a combined stream?

**UPDATE**

Trip$ is initialized in a component

```
 trips$ = this.tripService.updatedTrips$$.pipe(
    catchError(err => {
        this.errorMessageSubject.next(err.message);
        return EMPTY;
      }
    )
  );
```

**UPDATE 2**

Link to StarBlitz with the problem

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-combinelatest-repeat-pf7q2g?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: how is `trips$` defined?

Comment: `combineLatest` will emit the first time after all 3 source observables emit, then it will emit once any time ANY of the observables emit.  In your case, it will emit the initial state, then will emit after you call `addTrip()`.  What do you mean "avoid double firing"?  Which emission do you want to omit?

Comment: @BizzyBob updated the trip$ initialization. The 'zero' emit is fine with me since all the values are null/empty. When I submit an event using the `Subject` via `addTrip` function I observe two emissions to `updatedTrips$` (but the method `addTrip` is called only once)

Comment: Interesting. I would only expect one emission each time addTrip is called. Can you reproduce in a StackBlitz?

Comment: @ryzhman I set up a very similar simplified app https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-combinelatest-repeat. As you can see `combineLatest` is called only once each time I add a trip. Please share a full reproducible example.

Comment: @BizzyBob added the link to StartBlitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `updatedTrips$ combineLatest` is called twice is due to the following flow in your code:

1. Calling `addTrip` triggers `updatedTrips$ combineLatest` first time by assigning `this.newTripSubject.next(newTrip)`. One of `updatedTrips$'s` dependent Observables is `newTripSubject`
2. `updatedTrips$` triggers `allTripsWithCountries$ combineLatest` because it is one of its dependent Observables. This adds one trip to the list.
3. `maxTripId$` also gets to work because it depends on `updatedTrips$` as well.
4. `allTripsWithCountries$ combineLatest` is triggered again because it depends on `maxTripId$` in step 3, and adds the trip again. **And this is the problem**

See my slightly modified version [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-combinelatest-repeat-full). I removed the dependence of `allTripsWithCountries$ combineLatest` on `maxTripId$`. It is actually not required because you are going over each trip and increment its id, so the result is a list with sequential ids.

I'm sure you can further enhance the code and make it more elegant. But I hope the reason for the excessive call is clear.

Comment: thanks. Suggested fix worked. But I would like to understand the flow: my expectation was that the streams are sequenced from the top to the bottom: operations with `updatedTrips$` will be the first ones, then `maxTrip$` will be calculated (since it is below) and only then `allTripsWithCountries$` will be run. Does your explanation mean that the same stream cannot be referenced twice or it will cause circular emissions?

Answer (score 1):

As @Benny points out, your problem is due to essentially using `combinelatest()` with multiple instances of the same source observable.

From your StackBlitz:

```
  maxTripId$ = this.updatedTrips$.pipe(
    map(trips => Math.max(...trips.map(trip => (trip.id ? trip.id : 0)), 0))
  );
  
  allTripsWithCountries$ = combineLatest([
    this.updatedTrips$,
    this.maxTripId$
  ]).pipe(
    map(...)
  );
```

This is essentially the same as:

```
  allTripsWithCountries$ = combineLatest([
    this.updatedTrips$,
    this.updatedTrips$.pipe(
      map(trips => Math.max(...trips.map(trip => (trip.id ? trip.id : 0)), 0))
    )
  ]).pipe(
    map(...)
  );
```

So in reality, `allTripsWithCountries$` only depends on a `updatedTrips$`, so you don't need to define `maxTripId$` as a separate source and you don't need `combineLatest`:

```
  allTripsWithCountries$ = this.updatedTrips$.pipe(
      map(trips => {
        if (trips.length > 0) {
          const maxExistingId = Math.max(...trips.map(trip => (trip.id ? trip.id : 0)), 0);
          return trips.map(
            trip => ({
              ...trip,
              country: new Country(name),
              id: maxExistingId + 1
            } as Trip)
        );
      }
    })
```

Updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-combinelatest-repeat-mbbypx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftrip.service.ts)